# SwiftUI TextField cursor colour

Tags: textfield, swiftui, caret

Currently the cursor/caret for my SwiftUI `TextField` is *blue*. Is there an API for cursor colour or a workaround?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

EDIT: as pointed out below and in the documentation, my original answer (below) is now deprecated and you should use [`.tint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/tint(_:)) instead. Or if you want all text fields and other UI elements in your app to be the same you can customize your app’s global [`accentColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/accentcolor).

**Original answer**:

Tried it out and [`.accentColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/accentcolor(_:)) does the trick.

```
TextField(" Enter some text", text: $name)
    .accentColor(.yellow)
```

Comment: Didn't work for me but I'm trying this inside a *Catalyst app* (i.e., it's not a fully native `AppKit` macOS app) which might explain it :-(

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't available before macOS 11 (it is available in iOS 13, however).

Comment: Also in the future Apple docs as of (Jan '22) specify that .accentColor() will be deprecated in the future, and to use this instead:

.tint(.Yellow)

Comment: Using `.tint` is not working for me. Only `.accentColor` works.

Comment: iOS 16.0 .accentColor
iOS 16.1 and higher .tint
I use both to support all versions of 16

Comment: for me not working both accentColor & tintColor , please help

Answer (score 5):

The other answer didn't work for me but this did! It doesn't look like the cursor plays well with SwiftUI custom line spacing however...

```
extension NSTextView {
    open override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            insertionPointColor = .black
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Xcode 15, I just use the Assets resources, I added a Cursor color set. And I use it on the `tint` modifier.

[image]

For example

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyTextFieldStyle: TextFieldStyle {
    
    func _body(configuration: TextField<Self._Label>) -> some View {
        configuration
            .tint(Color(.cursor))
    }
}
```

And you can use it in the `textFieldStyle()` modifier like

```
.textFieldStyle(MyTextFieldStyle())
```

Answer (score 0):

This for me worked to change the cursor color for TextEditor. I put the code below as my app initialiser, thus making all of my apps cursors (TextEditor) pink.

```
init() {
    UITextView.appearance().tintColor = .systemPink
}
```

At the time of writing I have Xcode 13.4.1